# Minimalist Matrix Puzzle

Tags: visual

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 50 \end{bmatrix}$

This matrix represents a famous image. Because the answer may be easy to guess, a full explanation will be required in order to get credit for solving the puzzle.

Comment: I don't think this is a great puzzle - it's really just "recognize the reference", no? (Also, [tag:cryptic-clues] is for a specific type of crossword clue. Please check tag descriptions before using them.)

Comment: @Deusovi Recognizing the reference on its own wouldn't be enough. You had to also write $1, 2, 50$ in terms of Roman numerals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a representation of

> loss.jpg, a strip of the webcomic Ctrl+AltDel that was [made into a meme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_(comic)) because of its sudden tone shift compared to the rest of the comic.
>
>  The numbers here, expressed in Roman numerals, represent the four panels of the comic. Wikipedia gives this example of a "minimalist" version of the comic:
>  [image]