# You'll miss out on this IQ test

Tags: knowledge, visual

**Find the missing square, options are at the bottom.**

[image]

This is not your typical "IQ test" question.

Comment: Had it right away, done before: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/99672/minimalist-matrix-puzzle

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is

> The fourth square (50).

This question is a reference to

> The [Loss](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/loss) meme.

> Each number, when written in Roman numerals, corresponds to the position of the humans in its respective panel in the comic.
>  The lines correspond to non-human elements in the pictures.

This is the answer because

> 50 is "L" in Roman numerals, with the comic having one person standing and one person lying in bed in its final panel - with the bed showing in the answer as the horizontal line.